# Is boost::asio::thread_pool thread safe when posting tasks on multiple threads?

Tags: c++, boost, thread-safety, asio

I'm submitting more than one tasks to boost::asio::thread_pool concurrently. But official document does not talk about thread safe of boost::asio::thread_pool.

the boost lib version is 1.69. And my code like below:

```
/*define a thread pool*/    
boost::asio::thread_pool pool(4);

//on thread 1
boost::asio::post(pool, my_task_1);
...
//on thread 2
boost::asio::post(pool, my_task_2);
```

so I want to know is the code able to work on multiple threads

Answer (score 3):

`boost::asio::post` uses executor to post tasks into thread pool. Executor requirements are described under [this link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Executor1.html).
One of sentences is

> The executor copy constructor, comparison operators, and other member
>   functions defined in these requirements shall not introduce data races
>   as a result of concurrent calls to those functions from different
>   threads.

so your code is safe, you can call `post` from multiple threads.